# Google Sheets - Edit a cell by a viewer but it should not get saved in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 values which need to be edited by each viewer (according to their needs) who has access to the sheet. But those edits should not be saved so that when someone else views the sheet, they should see the owner's edits or original sheet.

Now there is a solution for giving them a copy which completely destroys the need for privacy. I cannot give a copy.

If it is not possible then here is what I would like to have.

Make a switch/button for 2% and 4%, so that a viewer can just click that switch from 2% to 4% or vice versa and he see calculations based on that %.

Obviously, this will also get saved but at least it would be easy to just click that switch and be done with it.

Comment: Use filterviews

Comment: @player0 I cannot share the entire sheet but I made a new one which mentions what needs to be changed. But there is no way to send you a DM with the link. If i paste here anyone will be able to edit then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest thing you can do is to create custom checkbox:

[image: 0]